# I can't access the xpath button location

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I need to access it with xpath. I wrote the code but I can't enter it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcLzC.png)

```
js_click(save_btn)
js_click(xpath('//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/footer/button[1]'))
```

I tried (**btn-primary,button,button[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcLzC.png),button[2]**)

Comment: //button[@data-testid='page-container-footer-next'] Try this xpath.

Comment: If the above doesn't work check the errors if not found look for iframes

Answer (score 0):

When the Xpath is too long - just avoid using it. A better approach will be to use CSS, you can do something like this:

```
 "button[class*='Part1-OfTheAtr][class*='Part2-OfTheAtr']"
```

CSS selectors can't find long attributes with spaces, so use `*=` to look for a string that is part of the class (using string contains and not full match). In your case this will be the code you need:

```
"button[class*='btn-primary'][class*='fotter-button']"
```

and if this doesn't work try this:

```
"button[class*='btn-primary'][class*='fotter-button'][data-testid*='footer-next']"
```